# Externalize jdbc properties Spring

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I want to put jdbc property file into the directory where pom file is. I put the path on pom as a system variable myApp./jdbc.properties
then on ${myApp}

but when running jetty:run it says ${myApp} cannot be opened. How can I fix this issue.
Please reply me.

Comment: You should post your pom

Comment: <SystemProperties><name>myApp</name><value>./jdbc.properties</value></SystemProperties>

Comment: Looks like `${myApp}` doesn't get substituted. Too few info to guess further.

Comment: thank you very much . I will try. Then how do i need to run the application? do i need to use any special command other than mvn jetty:run ?

Comment: <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>${myApp}</value>

Comment: I tried with ${project.basedir}/jdbc.properties But at the runtime it gives an exception. java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/D:/myproject/myproject/jdbc.properties]